# Should async F# functions include an Async ending like we add in C#?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I've been working with the `task{}` computations in a bunch of F# functions. If I had been writing this code in C#, I would name each method that returns `Task` or `Task<T>` with Async at the end. That's a well established convention in C#. I haven't even thought about it till now for F#.

Is it customary for F# apps to use that same Async naming style?

Comment: The answer appears to be no.  F# infers the return type.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/async

Comment: I have read somewhere - don't remember where - that you do the opposite for F# asyncs, so that it would be AsyncSomething. But for tasks, same as in C#.

Comment: It's in the F# Design Guidelines: "If there is a corresponding synchronous operation named Foo that returns a T, then the async operation should be named AsyncFoo and return Async<T>."

Comment: @BentTranberg That appears to be the answer. If you don't mind please post that as an answer so I may upvote and accept it. Since the Task based functions I'm working on don't have a synchronous counterpart as described in the document I'll assume the Async portion of the name can be omitted. Do you think that's the correct interpretation of the guideline?

Comment: Yes, I think so, but you should perhaps also consider whether it would make sense to have a synchronous version. If so, you might want to reserve that possibility for the future, even if you don't plan to implement it now. I won't take the time to write an answer, but do it yourself if you want. That's perfectly good practice on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Per Bent Tranberg's comment, the following section in the F# design guidelines answers this.
[Use Async for async programming at F# API boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/component-design-guidelines#use-asynct-for-async-programming-at-f-api-boundaries)

> If there is a corresponding synchronous operation named Operation that
> returns a T, then the async operation should be named `AsyncOperation`
> if it returns `Async<T>` or `OperationAsync` if it returns `Task<T>`

Since the functions I am working on don't have synchronous counterparts that need to be distinguished as described in the guideline, I'll omit the Async endings.